# How can I select the whole string except for the first character from a cell in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have multiple tables where 1 column contains a string which is a combination of a letter and a number. For example these values can range from B1 to B1000000. My present solution to automatically generate these values is `=CONCATENATE("B",1)` in the first row followed by `=CONCATENATE("B",RIGHT($A2,1)+1))`. Obviously this becomes a problem every time the number grows by a unit (ten, hundred, etc) making me change the formula to `RIGHT($A101,2)+1` when I reach a hundred, `RIGHT($A1001,3)+1` for a thousand and so on.

What is an elegant solution to selecting the whole string except for the first character from a cell?

Answer (score 0):

excel support the mid function

```
=mid(b1,2,99)
```

from byte #2 to 99 or whatever number you want
you could be fancy, but this is un-necessary

```
=mid(b1,2,len(b1)-1)
```